# Applescript How to get the filename from open -a "xx.app" [file] --args "someargs" in the applescript

Tags: applescript, filenames

I created a macos application launcher who is launching a apple script as the exec file.
The problem is that I can not intercept the file of the open command in the script or do not know or find somewhere on the net. The Launcher self does work ok. To demonstrate I set it on my github :

[CvrAppBash.app](https://github.com/christophecvr/macos-finder-selection-bashscript-launcher/tree/master/CvrAppBash.app/Contents)

when I run it out off terminal with open command for example: test.txt is just a simple text file.

open -a "CvrAppBash.app" "test.txt" --args "--some-arg-1" "--some-arg-2"

I can have all info needed in the launched apple script to work further with it. also the args.
But how to get the file name here "test.txt" in the script ?

At this time my display dialog out gives:

The Macos Hfs path is:

'MACOSHSIERRA:Applications:MacPorts:CvrAppBash.app:'

The Posix path is:

'/Applications/MacPorts/CvrAppBash.app'

The Application name is:

'CvrAppBash'

The args are:

'--some-arg-1'
'--some-arg-2'

What I wan't also to have is the filename here "test.txt" to work further with.

Comment: `current application` is the AppleScript runtime, not the target application.

Comment: What do You mean ?

Comment: You can either use `open` to pass items to the script's `open` handler, or `osascript` to pass items to the `run` handler, but there isn't a combined command.  You have a bunch of duplicate files in your GitHub link that get the Finder selection, but what is "test.txt" going to be?

Comment: Yes handling open finder selection is no problem at all. But the problem is that the open command which opens files or send files to a application to be opened by that selected application are send but which var in a applescript does contain those files. The args are passed fine. That test.txt is off course the file which I must open with the application CvrAppBash.app In this current script I now will just print the name of the file but the real goal later on is to off course do something whit that file this can be from adding changing and or editing it.

Comment: O sorry I also noted now those applescript files in resources these were remains of some tests but are not used at all I removed them out of the git repo.

Comment: What is the path to 'test.txt'?

Comment: the file test.txt is just a empty file and is located in /Applications/MacPorts the same path from which a start the open command.

Comment: What happens if you provide the full path to test.txt in the command line?

Comment: Just the same works fine . But still can't find de variable used to store the file path somewhere. Maybe there must be some extra in the plist file I don't. But the args from open command are passed. So I'm shure the open command sends also the file to open with the application question is in which variable or do we need to use a extra service or so for that.

Comment: The output of the command open -a "/Applications/MacPorts/CvrAppBash.app" "/Applications/MacPorts/test.txt" --args "--arg-1" "--arg-2"  is : The Macos Hfs path is:
'MACOSHSIERRA:Applications:MacPorts:CvrAppBash.app:'
The Posix path is:
'/Applications/MacPorts/CvrAppBash.app'
The Application name is:
'CvrAppBash'
The args are:
'--arg-1'
'--arg-2'

Answer (score 0):

I did not had a lot of response. Now found a solution to the problem.
Once You now it is very simple. It is only that you needed two sections in the apple script file. One section on run --- end run. Another on open -- end open. The applescript needs to be saved out of applescript editor using convert save as application. What also should work but does not is using osacompile -o Newapplication.app thescript.apple. At least it does not work on macos High Sierra 10.13.6. when using osacompile. Below the way how to do it in applescript.

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

    on run
    -- The on run used when using open -a command without a given
    -- file to open.
    -- also used when clicking on the application out of finder.
    -- Set here the code needed to execute you're selected program.
    end run
    
    on open
    -- On open used when you are using open -a ".app" "a existing
    -- file.
    -- Also used when you select files in finder and open them
    -- with this application.
    -- Set the code You wan't further here.
    end open
```

To look more examples on how to use this way of application launcher see the mentions code examples below. I set them my github. Quit possible that depending on You're macos version You need to rebuild the application by just saving the script in site as application with apple script editor.

I set the application bunch self on my git hub :

[The TestLaunchCvr.app on my git hub](https://github.com/christophecvr/macos-finder-selection-bashscript-launcher/tree/master/TestLaunchCvr.app/Contents)

I Added an example of practical use of this script to my git repo
[Gedit3 launcher](https://github.com/christophecvr/macos-finder-selection-bashscript-launcher/tree/master/Gedit3.app/Contents)

You can see the plain apple script code on :
[Gedit 3 launcher script](https://github.com/christophecvr/macos-finder-selection-bashscript-launcher/blob/master/Gedit3.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/Gedit3.applescript)

The macports installed gedit can now be used with commands :

```
open -a "Gedit3" "file1" "file2" --args "--new-window"
```

or

By clicking on the application self out of finder.

or

By selecting files in finder and then select Gedit3 out of applications list.

Comment: There is no spyware, the executable in the MacOS folder is the actual application.  Something needs to run the script - the `applet` or `droplet` executables are what does that, and are required for any script application.

Comment: Ter info I added example of effectif use from this script to launch in this example on all macos ways . With open -a command out of terminal or out of finder by clicking the application or use the application to open files in finder. Yes at this time the gedit is also installed as a command and the open icommand is not really needed  here but since we are on mac i just like to have it usable on macs way.

Comment: Today I just found out that solution above was already answered in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76447609/macos-getting-the-file-path-inside-a-shell-script-when-opening-a-file-as-an-appl/76460177#76460177  (took me 6 weeks to find a solution for this problem).